# matplotlib inline Python 2.7 %

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to run the following code, but I keep getting a Syntax Error. It runs sometimes on iPython notebook, but it's not stable.

The code is supposed to get a bubble chart of the variables set.

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('effort.csv')
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='setting', y='effort', s=df['country']*df['change']);
```

Answer (score 10):

[`%matplotlib inline`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/notebook.html#plotting) is an IPython-specific directive which causes IPython to display matplotlib plots in a notebook cell rather than in another window.

To run the code as a script use

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('effort.csv')
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='setting', y='effort', s=df['country']*df['change'])
plt.show()
```

---

- Use `plt.show()` to display the plot
- Note that semicolons are not necessary at the end of statements.